# Omit null rows in results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me figure this out...

I have a temporary table that has NULL values.  I want to only extract one record, representing rows that have data.  What I currently have in the table is

[TableSample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moVzV.jpg)

When I run the following statement,

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
WHERE SICK IS NOT NULL
AND VAC IS NOT NULL;

I want my results to be
[ResultsSample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWswT.jpg)

Comment: what is the rule if there are two non null values for a column... the sum,  the max, something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
select id, sum(sick) as sick, sum(vac) as vac
from #TempTable
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAX function..for this.

```
SELECT ID, MAX(SICK) SICK , MAX(VAC) VAC
FROM #TempTable
GROUP BY ID
```